# How can I make this picture print exactly (or almost exactly) the way it looks on screen?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, publishing, digital-printing, color-management

[image]

I have this image that is used as a cover page of a magazine I made.
When I print it, it prints a very dark image and does not show the spiky designs at all.

I saw some suggestions to use Photoshop curves but I'm not sure it's the same problem.

My monitor is not calibrated at all.
I'm using InDesign but the image is a JPG in RGB mode.

Comment: If your screen isn't calibrated [forget that you're also randomly changing profiles CMYK to RGB] even **you** have no idea what it actually looks like... & yes, it looks pretty dark to me too.

Comment: so what to do about this? will brightening this will help or using curve?

Comment: Well, you could randomly keep lightening the image until it prints vaguely similarly to what you see on screen, or you could calibrate the screen... & the rest of your workflow, so you at least know what it really looks like to start with.

Comment: okay so calibrating this will help? i'll do thid then thanks

Comment: Start with research on the subject of "Colour Management." Calibration is only one aspect of the issue. Whole books cover this single difficulty.

Comment: The trick is to "cripple" your monitor (which has a wider gamut than printed material) so that it shows the more limited capabilities of print more accurately. It's the opposite of what you're trying to do. Intuitive—it's not. Just knowing and teaching this has paid my rent for decades.

Comment: @Stan While your comment sort of reverse engineers the question (how can I make my screen look like my print output), I think that should be an answer. I would definitely upvote it.

Comment: Most home/office inkjet printers can't handle CMYK files. They are designed to print RGB images, with sRGB colour profiles.

Comment: @BillyKerr - I wasn't even going to go there... ;)

Comment: I would actually use the Levels instead of the Curves in Photoshop. After the crude calibration mentioned below, the two things you need to adjust are the white point (the white slider) and the gamma (the middle, gray slider) until you get the image the way you like it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Study Colour Management.

Find and worship "CMYK 2.0 by Rick McCleary." I use it as my course text.

Tip: What you should be trying to do is to get your screen to look like the print.

Begin by making your studio viewing conditions graphics-industry standard and stable. Block out all sources of variable illumination (windows). All illumination should be the correct colour temperature (5000°K), the correct brightness (500 lux - at the desk surface) without glare in a neutral background. Tape all switches and light sources so they don't change.

Profile your printer. Calibrate it. Find and print a standard IT-8 test image on standard paper without brighteners. Consult your printer (the thing) literature for the recommended printer-paper stock number.

Calibrate your monitor and adjust the gamma to recommended values. Display the test image on your monitor and adjust your monitor to match the print. Shield the monitor from the light spill you use to examine the print. Ideally, the print is in its own viewing area near the monitor. Shield the monitor from the viewing area lighting.

Now, you can begin to zero in on creating your miracle.
Compare the two standard images. They should match favourably.

The subject of how closely they match is a vital issue that I can't deal with here; but, there are test targets to help you determine how closely hues must match. The more closely you want your work to match reality will be a cost issue as there is expensive technology available to help you with proportionate expense to accuracy

The reason you must go to all this trouble is that printed (reflection copy) has a much more limited gamut, brightness, and contrast than any projected image. You must "cripple" your monitor to get them to match. It is a specialty shared by the photographer, graphic artist, pre-press service, and the print house.

WHEW.

Comment: for now i have calibrated my screen with windows 7 color calibration tool, I'll look into that book soon. But i'll have to say that my screen looks kind of dull in compare to previously.

Comment: Honestly, you cannot calibrate a screen manually. You need to spend the money on the hardware. Human eyes are so malleable that without considerable practise, they are so easily fooled. Hardware colorimeters are harder to fool.

Comment: "Study Colour Management." Talk about an answer that is both annoyingly perfect and yet so boringly depressive at the same time. Isn't there an EASY and FUN way?! haha

Comment: @mayersdesign The easiest way is to hire me (U$650/day + expenses). Students tell me I'm the "Tom Waits" of graphic design. Slightly more difficult would be to take my Colour College course. 3rd, find out how close you have to be: ∆E (one ∆E = a just noticeable difference) and buy the necessary instrumentation to achieve that. Hang around printers (the people) and pre-press people. Hardest of all is to work under pressure of deadline in ignorance. (Maybe I should put my course online.)

Comment: haha Well sign me up!

Comment: You have a pretty good list of approaches, ranked by difficulty. Where does "explain to the head of marketing that you need more time and money to complete the assignment because of this thing called 'color management.'" fit in that list? =)

Comment: True, @Tatsujin. You can't get it anywhere near perfect manually. But you can likely get it close enough for the OP's current situation.

Comment: @CortAmmon Great question to ask with many variations. Perhaps the answers will give some insight to your mis-understanding. The first is that "color management" ***saves*** you time and money—which is why it's used. Who would spend *more* time and money than is necessary? I couldn't cover, "How close must the match be" here, now. Many can accept "close-enough."